# Can't access drawables when app isn't completely loaded

Tags: android, android-drawable

So I have an app that listens for `DeviceAdminReceiver.OnPasswordFailed`. This means that the app is started any time that event is called. I want to make a notification go when this happens.

The problem is at the part it tries to construct the notification. When I run the app from the **GUI**, it works perfectly, but when it's opened from the event, it gets the **null** error when setting the `setSmallIcon` of the `Notification Builder`.

It seems like the `drawable` image resources aren't getting loaded.

Any ideas?